# Status bar icon can't remove after destroy

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

Destroy app solved! Thanks for help! Right now activity is destroy but status icon still appear on status bar. Can you help me with remove icon in the same time when app is closing? I suspect onDestroy section problem...

```
private static final int NOTIF_ID = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_jajko);

text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butStart);
miekko = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butMiekko);
srednio = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butSrednio);
twardo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butTwardo);

miekko.setOnClickListener(this);
srednio.setOnClickListener(this);
twardo.setOnClickListener(this);
play.setOnClickListener(this);

mp = MediaPlayer.create(Jajko.this, R.raw.alarm);

showNotification(this);
}


public static void showNotification(Context context) {
    final Intent result_intent = new Intent(context, Jajko.class);

    result_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);              

    TaskStackBuilder stack_builder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stack_builder.addParentStack(Jajko.class);
    stack_builder.addNextIntent(result_intent);


    PendingIntent pending_intent = stack_builder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

    Resources res = context.getResources();
    builder.setContentIntent(pending_intent)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.icon))
        .setTicker("test")
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .setContentTitle("title")
        .setContentInfo("cinfo")
        .setContentText("ctext");
    Notification n = builder.build();
    n.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT; 

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(NOTIF_ID, n);     
}

public void onDestroy() {
try {
    mp.release();
    if (isFinishing()) {
        notificationManager.cancel(NOTIF_ID);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
}
super.onDestroy();

}
```

Comment: does `catch (Exception e)` catches anything? place an output there, do not left `catch` block empty

Comment: OK but even if I change: public void onDestroy() {
    if (mp !=null) mp.release();
    if (isFinishing()) {
        notificationManager.cancel(NOTIF_ID);
    }

super.onDestroy();
} it doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if(isFinishing()){
            notificationManager.cancelAll();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: I've got NullPointerException at line   notificationManager.cancel(NOTIF_ID);

Answer (score 0):

try to call "killProcess" method

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```